# Renaming json key attribute using python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying to rename keys of json data but I don't seem to get what I am looking for. Could you please point the issue?

```
import json

if __name__ == '__main__':

    json_data = [
        {
            "Aa": "A1 value",
            "Ab": "A2 Value",
            "Ac": "0",
            "Ad": "245",
            "Ae": "some value"
        },
        {
            "Aa": "A1 value2",
            "Ab": "A2 Value2",
            "Ac": "1",
            "Ad": "225",
            "Ae": "some value2"
        }
        ]

    vcounter = 1
    for item in json_data:      
        for oldKey,v in item.items():
            newKey = 'X'+str(vcounter)
            #print(newKey)
            item[newKey] = item.pop(oldKey)
            vcounter += 1
        print('Item:'+str(item))
        print('-----------------')
        vcounter = 1
```

output

```
Item:{'Ab': 'A2 Value', 'X4': 'some value', 'X5': 'A1 value', 'X6': '0', 'X7': '245'}
-----------------
Item:{'Ab': 'A2 Value2', 'X4': 'some value2', 'X5': 'A1 value2', 'X6': '1', 'X7': '225'}
-----------------
```

Expected output
Keys to be renamed as X1 to the length of the items in the list. In this case it's X1 to X5

```
Item:{'X2': 'A2 Value', 'X5': 'some value', 'X1': 'A1 value', 'X3': '0', 'X4': '245'}
-----------------
Item:{'X2': 'A2 Value2', 'X5': 'some value2', 'X1': 'A1 value2', 'X3': '1', 'X4': '225'}
-----------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing that you're using Python 3.7+, where dict keys are ordered, you can use a dict comprehension to iterate over an enumeration of dict values to build a new dict with the new keys that are generated by concatenating `'X'` with the enumerated index:

```
[{'X%s' % i: v for i, v in enumerate(d.values(), 1)} for d in json_data]
```

This returns:

```
[{'X1': 'A1 value',
  'X2': 'A2 Value',
  'X3': '0',
  'X4': '245',
  'X5': 'some value'},
 {'X1': 'A1 value2',
  'X2': 'A2 Value2',
  'X3': '1',
  'X4': '225',
  'X5': 'some value2'}]
```